# Angular 1.1.5 or Angular 1.0.7

Tags: angularjs

What is the difference between Angular monochromatic-rainbow (1.0.7) or triangle squarification (1.1.5)?

Also if I am trying to develop a responsive website which is going to be used heavily on mobile devices, should I use one rather than the other?

Comment: This title should be worded more specifically but otherwise I think it's a good question.

Comment: Except for no research whatsoever. Did you google either of these things? Did you learn anything about them?

Comment: Probably Angular 1.2 since it should be stable by the time you end development. I've used 1.1.5 on a mobile site in production without problem

Comment: 1.0.7 for prod usage. Never use unstable version for Prod.

Comment: I did my research and I was confused, that's why I posted here.
Some of my research suggested that 1.1.x have got mobile components like ng-tap which 1.0.x do not have?

Why do they have 2 different version sets? That is my main confusion. 

I am kinda excited for 1.2 to come out, but was wondering what I should use till then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are developing new website you should have gone with *1.1.x*, since those version will eventually become *1.2.0*. However, at the time of writing this ***1.2.0rc1** is already available for download*.

Short explanation of 1.0.x-1.1.x:

> **Versioning conventions**
>
> **1.0.x** will receive only bug fixes backported from 1.1.x branch and will be supported until 1.2 is released
>
> **1.1.x** will receive features and bugfixes and might contain breaking changes in between minor releases
>
> **1.2.x** will become stable (a bugfix branch) based on the last 1.1.x release

You have more details in [roadmap document](http://blog.angularjs.org/2012/07/angularjs-10-12-roadmap.html).

Comment: Thanks for this Nenad, but why do they have 1.0.x and 1.1.x, why not just one set of versions?

Comment: It's explained in the roadmap document in more detail, but: 1.1.x version are stable, but they do not guaranty that external API would not change. 1.0.x versions are maintained to ensure that sites deployed with previous 1.0.x versions would not break (APIs did not change). At the end 1.2 versions is not backward compatible with 1.0.x.